# How to add CNAME in tinydns for reset gmail password?

Tags: cname-record, tinydns

I want to reset my gmail password ( I added my domain on google app ).
In this link http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=112038 Google says too add Reset the administrator password CNAME too my domain
How I can add this CNAME on debian with tinydns?!

Comment: The actual question here is, "How do I add a CNAME to tinydns?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a CNAME is very easy:

```
Cgoogle9d97d7f266ee521d:google.com:3600
```

The format is the letter C, followed by the hostname in the DNS zone that'll be the alias, a colon, the destination address, a colon, then the TTL.

Comment: How I shold make this as subdomain on mydomain.com like google9d97d7f266ee521d.mydomain.com

Comment: I added this line Cgooglea3bf85c5f1a47268.mydomain.com:google.com:3600 too data file, Is it true?!